# Function of Filling

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I wants to code a rectangle that filling up every day for example in one precent. Thats the general idea.

However, my main problem is how filling it? For example, every day the rectangle need to up by a 1% precent. So, I needs to fill the rectangle on 1/100 from the rectangle width.

For example, I have a 100px width on my rectangle, and I need to change the background of the first 1px only. it just like a battery... Any suggestions? I would like to do it with html or css, but I'm not sure if its possible so JavaScript/ jQuery will be fine too.

Thanks.

Comment: What are your trials so far? Please show us your attempts, your code and specifiy what exactly is not working

Comment: Do you mean every day user visits `document`?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a little code in jquery that i think does what you want, what i've done is put a div with 0px width inside another with 100px width and then programmatically change the width of the first in base to the second. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log($("#div1"));
  $("#div2").css("width",parseInt($("#div1").css("width"))/2+"px")
})
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1" style="border: 1px solid red; width:100px; height:100px;">
<div id="div2" style="background-color: blue; width:0px; height:100px"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```